# Installing Bootstrap Deps: can't find phython-ros for ARMv8

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Console:

```
root@ubuntu:~# apt-get install python-ros
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python-ros
root@ubuntu:~#
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/242765/installing-bootstrap-deps:-can%27t-find-phython-ros-for-armv8/) by [mark.douglas@nxp.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/27870/mark.douglas@nxp.com/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-08-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm guessing -- as you didn't tell us -- that you are trying to follow the [Installation/Source](http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Source) instructions for Kinetic (but the initial steps are pretty similar for other ROS releases). If so, I think you've misinterpreted the shown commands.

Step 1.1 (*Prerequisites - Installing bootstrap dependencies*) asks you to run:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-rosdep python-rosinstall-generator python-wstool python-ros
install build-essential
```

Perhaps the layout could be improved, but that is supposed to be a single line, like so:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-rosdep python-rosinstall-generator python-wstool python-rosinstall build-essential
```

Note `python-rosinstall`, not `python-ros`.

There is no package `python-ros` (at least not in ROS), hence the error message you received.

In general: the wiki prefixes commands with either `$` or `#`. This is standard Linux 'terminology': the `$` is for commands executed as a normal user, the `#` for commands executed as root.

This same formatting also gives you a hint where commands begin and end: everything following a `$` or `#` is a single command, even if it is line-wrapped. In your case there is only a single `$`, so everything following it should be on a single line.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-08-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mark.douglas@nxp.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/27870/mark.douglas@nxp.com/) on 2016-08-31**:
oh!!! Thank you, thank you, thank you! this is infact totally my misinterpretation.
--- Yes: please change the build from source step to "$ sudo apt-get install python-rosdep python-rosinstall-generator python-wstool python-rosinstall build-essential"

**Comment by [mark.douglas@nxp.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/27870/mark.douglas@nxp.com/) on 2016-08-31**:
so I cannot build from source with the Indigo release base?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-09-01**:\

> so I cannot build from source with the Indigo release base?

I'm not sure I understand you: what makes you think that?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-09-01**:\

> Yes: please change the build from source step to [..]

I also don't completely understand this: the wiki already has all the packages on a single line, it's *your browser* that wraps it so it becomes two lines.

**Comment by [mark.douglas@nxp.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/27870/mark.douglas@nxp.com/) on 2016-09-01**:
yes thanks the wrap occurred at an inconvenient point

and ->
root@ubuntu:~# printenv | grep ROS_DISTRO
ROS_DISTRO=indigo

so I'm good! Thanks!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-09-01**:
Good to hear your got it to work.

**Comment by [mark.douglas@nxp.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/27870/mark.douglas@nxp.com/) on 2016-09-01**:
fantastic support!!!
--- I now have been able to run the tutorials (well the ones that don't depend on the pre-built tutorial package) and appear to have a fully running "Bare Bones" install of ROS on the NXP LS2088ARDB (ARMv8 A72) and the LS2080ARDB (ARMv8 A57) targets.

**Comment by [mark.douglas@nxp.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/27870/mark.douglas@nxp.com/) on 2016-09-01**:
I am not sure what to do about the "$ sudo apt-get install ros--ros-tutorials" package as these are prolly NOT ARMv8 binaries :-)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-09-02**:
Very nice. I think the users over at [discourse.ros.org/c/embedded](http://discourse.ros.org/c/embedded) would be interested in hearing that. You could perhaps submit a short post detailing any obstacles you encountered, or anything you changed to the installation instructions.